# Docker MySQL no output

Tags: mysql, docker

Docker for Windows

I have a machine set up with 2 containers.  They are both running the standard mysql image.  One is set up to be the server, and I am linking to it from the other and attempting to run mysql commands.

Ideally, I would like to be able to do this all through the command prompt so I can call it through Python.

I was able to run a few commands error-free and attempted to place my name into the Username table of myDB.

When I run the command:

```
docker exec sqlserverClient mysql -uroot -ppassword -e"use myDB" -e"select * from Usernames"
```

I get back the output:

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure
```

**And nothing else.**

**Where is my table?  Even if the insert went wrong, shouldn't I at least see a blank table?**

I expected to see something like this:

```
+------------+-------------+
| firstname  | lastname    |
+------------+-------------+
| First      | Last       |
+------------+-------------+
```

"docker logs sqlserverClient" doesn't have it.  So where did it go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `docker exec -it`, to have tty and the output

But remember [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/exec/) is for debug only.

The best practice is to have a docker container with:

- an entrypoint set to sqlserverClient
- a cmd that you pass in parameter when running a transient container.

That is:

```
docker run --rm -it sqlimage mysql -uroot -ppassword -e"use myDB" -e"select * from Usernames"
```

Once the command is executed, the container stopped and is rmeoved.

That means you can have an alias like:

```
alias drs='docker run --rm -it sqlimage'
```

And call:

```
drs mysql -uroot -ppassword -e"use myDB" -e"select * from Usernames"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.


Unfortunately, -it didn't help.  However, I was able to verify that the create and insert commands were somewhat successful as if I try to say:


docker exec -it sqlserverClient mysql -uroot -ppassword -e"use SNOTGARBAGEFAKEDB"


I do get the error output that this DB does not exist.


If I need to try your best practice solution, I will, but first I will ask if you have any other ideas...is stdout getting redirected somewhere?

Comment: I also tried with your other solution but I am getting the error 2002 - "Cant connect to local MySQL server through socket 'var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'.  sqlserver.exe is running when I view processes in task manager.  But maybe that's an issue for a different thread...

Comment: @MichaelTedford Not sure about the docker exec issue: I have seen comment like https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10132#issuecomment-71963093, which could explain it (if the main process is in background)